# Karate -Generate random alphanumeric string in the current feature file

Tags: string, random, karate

```
I am trying to generate alphanumeric string of length 5 in Karate.I am trying the below code.


Feature: Test user

 Background:

   Given url AM_HOST  
"  
   * def random_string =  

    function(s) {  
      var text = "";  
      var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";  
      for (var i = 0; i < s; i++)  
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));  
      return text;  
    }  

    * def sessionId =  random_string(5)  
    * print sessionId  
"  
   >Scenario: Verify return user  
    Given path 'user/<sessionId>'  
    When method get  
    Then status 404  
    And match response.message == "User Not Found"
```

I am not able to run this.Can you please let me know where the code has issues.The sessionId is not printed in cucumber report also.Should the quotes before and after function be removed in the feature file.The function gets printed in report. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see syntax related issues only, Try this,

```
Feature: Test user

 Background:
 Given url AM_HOST
 * def random_string =
 """
 function(s) {
   var text = "";
   var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
   for (var i = 0; i < s; i++)
     text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
   return text;
 }
 """
 * def sessionId =  random_string(5)

Scenario: Verify return user 
 Given path 'user/' ,sessionId 
 When method get 
 Then status 404 
 And match response.message == "User Not Found"
```

Comment: Hi Babu,I wanted to know if i can place this function in karate-config.js and use the alpha numeric value across all feature files.Please let me know.

Comment: @SSRSeln yes you can. if you having standard karate-config.js with `config` variable which is returned , do `config.random_string = <your function>`. then from your feature simply use `* def sessionId =  random_string(5)`